# how to get tabbed data in ionic view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, navbar

I am sending a http request in controller and the view is rendering the data from web-services at load time. One of the web-service is taking long time to finish,controller code :

```
  $scope.doRefresh = function() {
        //$http.get('http://inda208350.in.fid-intl.com:9090/appstatus/')
    $http.get('http://inda232218.in.fid-intl.com:9090/appstatus/')
        .success(function(newItems) {
         $scope.content  = newItems;
         })
         .finally(function() {
           // Stop the ion-refresher from spinning
           $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
         });
      };
$ionicLoading.show({
  content: 'Loading',
  animation: 'fade-in',
  showBackdrop: true,
  maxWidth: 200,
  showDelay: 10
});


 // DataTables configurable options
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withDisplayLength(10)
    .withOption('bLengthChange', false);


/* Get App Status */
$http.get('http://inda232218.in.fid-intl.com:9090/appstatus/').success(function(responseAppsData){
  $ionicLoading.hide();
  $scope.content = responseAppsData;
  $scope.appNm = $stateParams.appName;
  $scope.appSt = $stateParams.appStatus;  
  })
   .error(function(responseAppsData){
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    alert("Details Status Please call EPS for support..!!");
   })
 $ionicLoading.show({
  content: 'Loading',
  animation: 'fade-in',
  showBackdrop: true,
  maxWidth: 200,
  showDelay: 10
});    
/* Get Index Based Issues*/
$http.get('http://inda232218.in.fid-intl.com:9090/indexinfo/').success(function(responseAppsData){    
    $scope.content1 = responseAppsData;
    $scope.app = $stateParams.appName;
     })
     .error(function(responseAppsData){
     $ionicLoading.hide();
     alert("Details Status Please call EPS for support..!!");
     })

/* Get Holding  Based Issues*/
$http.get('http://inda232218.in.fid-intl.com:9090/holdinginfo/').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.content2 = data;
    })
    .error(function(responseAppsData){
     $ionicLoading.hide();
     alert("Details Status Please call EPS for support..!!");
    })
/* Get Cash  Based Issues*/
$http.get('http://inda232218.in.fid-intl.com:9090/cashdata/').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.content4 = data;
})
 .error(function(responseAppsData){
 $ionicLoading.hide();
alert("Details Status Please call EPS for support..!!");
 })

/* Get Discovery Based Issues*/     
$http.get('http://inda232218.in.fid-intl.com:9090/discovery_details/').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    $scope.content3 = data;
})

.error(function(responseAppsData){
 $ionicLoading.hide();
alert("Please call EPS for support..!!");
})
$ionicLoading.hide();


})
```

controller also contains the services as :
controller('DetailStatusCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $http, $timeout, $ionicLoading, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, $q)

In a single, view I want a tabular/tabbed data like one would get using the w3 navbars and on clicking one bar, I would get data from 1 web-service and on other tab click I would get data from other web-service. One of the solution I am thinking of is breaking the controller into 2 and then call the specific controller on tab click. Can anyone help what would be the approach?